# Custom run level

Tags: linux, init

I recall in the past creating a custom run (init) level. Has anyone else come across that? I'm wanting to have a run level invoked in specific conditions. I've searched through current documentation. I can't remember for the life of me how we did it previously.

Comment: In the past, as in, with a traditional init that uses `/etc/inittab`? Or with systemd, which has targets and not “runlevels”?

Comment: i remember that there were a few unused run levels that you could modify

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to runlevels: the processes monitored by init (mostly, instances of `getty` or variants thereof), and the processes started/stopped by a one-shot process when entering the runlevel.

Both of these are defined in the `inittab`: the terminals have `respawn` type, while the one-shot has `wait` type.

One Debian at least, the script `/etc/init.d/rc` is responsible for entering a runlevel, this will execute all scripts in `/etc/rc?.d/` (with `?` being the new runlevel) in numerical order, first all `K??` scripts with an argument of `stop`, then all `S??` scripts with an argument of `start`.

These scripts are usually symlinks to the real scripts, below `/etc/init.d`. Any service that should be started in a runlevel should be linked to a name that begins with `S` and two numbers, any service that should be stopped should be linked to a name that begins with `K` and two numbers.

The `update-rc.d` tool can do this for you on Debian, if you use another distribution, a similar mechanism should exist. Debian defines runlevels 2 through 5 to be the same, so you can just pick one and start modifying it against the default; other distributions might have different defaults.